# Benefit of remote wipe when the drive is encrypted?

Tags: deletion

How much is "remote wipe" beneficial for *company data protection* on company laptops, assuming that the storage is encrypted?

I understand it so that only determined, targeting attackers are interested in confidential company data. For sure they will not just turn the stolen laptop on and connect to the Internet. If so, what threat is mitigated by having a remote wipe agent?

Answer (score 1):

It protects the device from attacks on the login process. If I can log in, then your encryption is meaningless.

Comment: Do you mean that the mitigated threat is "**both** stolen device and compromised user's password"?

Comment: Well, discovering the password is a secondary issue, but remote wipe 's primary effect is not to protect credentials.

Comment: To make sure I understand, I'll repeat the question: what is the threat that is mitigated by the remote wipe feature?

Comment: That no one can access the data on the device. If encryption is used, the primary threat is someone logging in to access the data or guessing the encryption password.

Comment: Remote wipe requires network, so only accessing the network resources (not local data) is mitigated. To mitigate the threat "compromised account is accessing protected network resources" account suspension would achieve the same result as remote wiping - correct?

Comment: No. The laptop has local login creds. Remote wipe just needs internet access. If someone wrote down their password in a book carried with their laptop bag. The bag gets stolen. Theif takes laptop home, turns it on and logs in. Account suspension does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not worth the effort to have this feature if your storage is fully encrypted with a modern encryption algorithm like >AES-128 and an unpredictable, random and long (>8 characters) password. For sure, if the storage get wiped, there is no data any longer which potentially could get decrypted. But anyway if the encryption is well done, the data also couldnt get decrypted.

I think in your case, this feature would be more to calm down and dont fall in panic. But it's the same result like wipe your storage more than one time with random data -> good feeling, not more secure than wipe it once.

Comment: Remote wipe is free, easy to set up, and easy to use. And it mitigates credential weaknesses. It's called "defence-in-depth" and is *certainly not panic or fear*. There is no "silver bullet" in security. Including encryption.

Comment: I understand your point. But any encryption with weak credentials are useless and in case of the storage got stolen there is only a little chance of the attacker connect the device to the internet. Pragmatically: remote-wipe mitigates credential weaknesses for encrypted devices. In reality: use random, long credentials and e.g. a password-manager would be much more efficient than speculating the attacker would connect to the internet.

Comment: Nope. You are making a great number of assumptions that simply do not reflect reality. The question is about corporate laptops.  You cannot force people to use "long random passwords" and you cannot stop them from writing it down.

Comment: But that is the point: you CAN force them. If a company forces its employees to use credentials defined in a well credential policy you have the full control over the used devices. If you let do people what people do - use weak credentials for memorize reasons - you give the control to the potential attacker. In my opinion with a remote wipe you build a protection layer which is more pseudo-secure than secure. Anyways I think this discussion is based more on opinion than facts because the result is individual. That's why I mentioned before that I understand your point.

Comment: You cannot force users to use random passwords. You can only force some level of complexity. And doing that tends to create insecure passwords. You do not understand the realities in this space.

Comment: @schroeder Scenario -- bitlocker whole drive encryption -- bitlocker password controlled by IT, cannot boot without it, and the password is NOT chosen NOR changeable by the end user.  If I have strong whole drive encryption with TPM and a strong encryption password -- what does remote wipe really add?  I can think of a stolen laptop while it is still powered on.

Comment: @avery_larry and my above comments still apply: the user will write down this strong, IT-created and controlled password.

Comment: @schroeder So you need an end user dumb enough to write down a good password; a thief smart enough or lucky enough to get/find/extort this password, but dumb enough to boot up the computer and get it connected to the internet.  I'm not saying this obviates the incremental increase in security -- I'm just trying to really understand from a cost/risk analysis and perspective.  I would think the odds would be very very small that *good* whole drive encryption gets defeated but remote wipe is successful.  Clearly it can and does happen -- but that doesn't mean it warrants the cost in all cases.

Comment: Side note -- I did not find free remote wipe software for corporate use, but to be fair I only Google researched it for 2 minutes.

Comment: @avery_larry you have no idea how many times I've seen end-users write down the bitlocker password on a sticky note and place it on the laptop. You dismiss them as "dumb", but if they are forced to use a "strong" password that someone else created, and they can't use a password manager (since it is locked up in the encrypted laptop), what else are they to do? I'll repeat my comment above: "You do not understand the realities in this space."

Comment: It's worth noting that programs that do remote wipe make for great attack vectors